# Find the eccentric angles of the extremities of the latus recta of the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$.

Tags: trigonometry, conic-sections

I am having an issue where I am getting two different answers and I am not able to figure out where is the mistake. Both methods seems correct to me.

> Find the eccentric angles of the extremities of the latus recta of the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$.
> The centre of the ellipse is at origin.

Any point in an ellipse P is $(acos(θ), bsin(θ))$, the coordinates of one end of the latus recta are $(ae, \frac{b^2}{a})$.
therefore, $(acos(θ), bsin(θ)) = (ae, \frac{b^2}{a})$
thus, $cos(θ)=e$ and $sin(θ)=\frac{b}{a}$,
$\implies tan(θ)=\frac{b}{ae}$,hence $θ=arctan(\frac{b}{ae})$

For a traingle with perpendicular, $P=\frac{b^2}{a}$, and base, $B=ae$,
$tan(θ) = \frac{P}{B} = \frac{\frac{b^2}{a}}{ae} = \frac{b^2}{a^2e}$.
Hence, $θ=arctan(\frac{b^2}{a^2e})$

does this mean $\frac{b}{a} = 1$? which is only true for circles.

What am I doing wrong please help...

Comment: The eccentric angle is not the same as the polar angle.  So only the first answer is correct.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot, I had to draw a graph in order to understand the difference between the angles, couldn't find anything on the internet.